# How to auto-start hostapd

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, startup

I've installed Ubuntu Server on my Orange Pi Zero. It should act like wifi access point. In order to start I normally have to do the following manually:

```
/etc/init.d/hostapd start
/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start
```

If I install it using update-rc.d, hostapd fails and I guess it's because wlan0 is not ready at that time. Do I have to call above start commands on wlan0 interface up event or there is better way to auto-start them on boot?

This is my Ubuntu version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```